# setting text in mat-select angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-select` field like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (click)="onSelectOpen()" placeholder="Store" (selectionChange)="setStoreTitle($event)" title="Store" formControlName="store" id="store" name="store">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let store of stores" [value]="store.Title">
            {{store.Title}}
            <span class="store-address">{{store.Address}}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

When I try to access the value I get Store Title and that's fine but in the drop down it also shows the span as written in the code. How to hide that span text in select box?

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear from your question but from your comments, it looks like what you are looking for is to set the have the `span` tag available in the `mat-option` but it should not appear once selected. What you are looking for is [MatSelectTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger). As per the docs

> MatSelectTrigger allows the user to customize the trigger that is displayed when the select has a value.

So all you need to do is display the `formControl` value in `mat-select-trigger`

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (click)="onSelectOpen()" placeholder="Store" (selectionChange)="setStoreTitle($event)" title="Store" formControlName="store" id="store" name="store">
        <mat-select-trigger>
            {{form.get('store').value}} <!-- where form is the name of your FormGroup -->
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let store of stores" [value]="store.Title">
            {{store.Title}}
            <span class="store-address">{{store.Address}}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use mat-select-trigger and create a function to return the value you need

In ts file

```
getOptionDisplayValue(title: string): yourInterface {
    let address;
    address = yourData.find(data => data.title=== title);   
    return address;
}
```

in html

```
<mat-select-trigger>
        {{getOptionDisplayValue(Form.get('store').value).Title}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        {{getOptionDisplayValue(Form.get('store').value).Address}}   
</mat-select-trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add it like this below, add span tag for the store.tile also.

```
<mat-select (click)="onSelectOpen()" placeholder="Store" (selectionChange)="setStoreTitle($event)"
                                         title="Store"
                                         formControlName="store" id="store" name="store">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let store of stores" [value]="store.Title">
                                 <span class="store-address"> {{store?.Title}}</span>
                                  <span class="store-address">{{store?.Address}}</span>
                                </mat-option>
                              </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the span to be rendered. You can hide it via css.

```
.store-address {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can use [hidden] attribute, if you need it to be conditional.